# XML traversing to find the node name

Tags: java, xml

Following is a string containing an XML file that specifies folder structure

```
     String xml ="<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>" +
                    "<folder name=\"c\">" +
                        "<folder name=\"program files\">" +
                            "<folder name=\"uninstall information\" />" +
                        "</folder>" +
                        "<folder name=\"users\" />" +
                    "</folder>";
```

If user enter initial letter of the folder the method must return the folder name (following is part of it method i have tried)

```
DocumentBuilder builder = 
    DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
            InputSource src = new InputSource();
            src.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xml));
            Document doc = builder.parse(src);          
            List<String> listObj = new ArrayList<String>();
            if(doc.getElementsByTagName("folder").item(0) != null){
    System.out.println(doc.getElementsByTagName("folder").item(0).getNodeValue());}
```

But in my method i always get null. How do I iterate and find out the folder name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`name` is an Attribute of the Folder tag, so you have to use the following code:

```
System.out.println(doc.getElementsByTagName("folder").item(0).getAttributes().getNamedItem("name").getNodeValue());
```